# SPOJ Most Solved #11, CANDY I with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Problem statement link here: http://www.spoj.com/problems/CANDY/

```
N=input('')
sum=0
z=0
A=N
while N!=-1:
   if 1<=N<=10000:
        N-=1
        x=input('')
        if x<1000:
            sum=x+sum
            z+=1
            if (sum/float(z))==int(sum/float(z)) and z==A:
                print (sum/z)
            elif z==A:
                print -1
                print ''
        else:
            sum=0
            N=input('')
            z=0
            A=N
            continue
   else:
       sum=0
       N=input('')
       z=0
       A=N
       continue
else:
    quit()
```

I keep on getting runtime error with (NZEC) with this. All of my sample outputs are correct.

This bit is supposed to find the average and print it. If average isn't integral, it prints -1.

```
if 1<=N<=10000:
        N-=1
        x=input('')
        if x<1000:
            sum=x+sum
            z+=1
            if (sum/float(z))==int(sum/float(z)) and z==A:
                print (sum/z)
            elif z==A:
                print -1
                print ''
```

I am using print '' to get a new line. This is not necessary since I'm not getting WA, but still thought I'd put it out there. I have already submitted it without "print ''" and it gives me the same error.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What runtime error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
# your code goes here

while True:
    i = int(input())
    if i != -1:
        L1 = []
        for n in range(0, i):
            L1.append(int(input()))
        L = L1
 
        avg = sum(L)//len(L)
 
        if sum(L) == avg * len(L):
            cnt = 0 
            for t1 in range(0,len(L)):
                if avg -L[t1] < 0:
 
                    cnt += L[t1] -avg
 
            print(cnt)   
        else:
            print(-1)
    else:
        break
```